# Bulb size of a SYLVANIA CF13EL?

Tags: bulb

The [SYLVANIA CF13EL](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0049OVDXG) in my bathroom vent just died. I want to replace it with an LED. There is not a lot of room in the fixture. Is the bulb equivalent to an A19? If not, what size should I get?

Comment: The CF13EL actually comes in a few styles with potentially different bases, so it's difficult to answer.  Are you trying to order it online or can you just take the bulb with you to a hardware store and compare directly with other bulbs?

Answer (score 1):

If the existing CFL lamp was positioned in the fixture to emit light from it's side as opposed to its end then it is unlikely to be a suitable LED unit that would give satisfactory performance. Most LED units are designed to be used in a manner where the light is mainly emitted from the end of the unit away from the screw base.

Comment: I have offered a [Cree 9.5 Watt LED Soft White Light Bulb A19](http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00GGCASXU#productDetails), which seems to have round light distribution and [has a dark spot in the center](http://www.amazon.com/review/RC4QPTVOG2Q1Z/ref=cm_cr_dp_title?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B00GGCASXU&channel=detail-glance&nodeID=228013&store=hi). I will update when it arrives and I install it.